# Parse String to DateTime To String("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy") on Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, datetime

I have this on my aspx.cs file

```
var RecordID = db.Records.Where(m => m.EmployeeID == employee.EmployeeID).ToList();

dltRecordDate.DataSource = RecordID;
dltRecordDate.DataBind();
```

And have this in `.aspx`:

```
 <asp:LinkButton CssClass="list-group-item" Width="100%" BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="Medium" ID="lbnDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitDate") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("RecordNumber") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

My **VisitDate** is a **string**. I want to do something like

```
Text='<%#DateTime.Parse(Bind("VisitDate")).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy")%>'
```

but this dows not work. Thank you

another option is just to print incrementing number
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: can you please tell us the format of VisitDate string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a method(`GetValidDate`) in the back-end and use like the following:

```
protected string GetValidDate(object inputDate)
{
    DateTime dateObject;
    if (inputDate != null)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(inputDate.ToString(), out dateObject))
        {
            return dateObject.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
        }               
    }
    return "invalid Input";
}
```

mark-up will be:

```
Text=<%# GetValidDate(Eval("VisitDate"))%>
```

So you will get the date in required format if it is convertible(valid date) or else the particular textbox will show text as `"invalid Input"`

updates :

In the comment you are converting the object to string using `(string)Eval("VisitDate")` but it is not good, if the bound value is `null` so to avoid this we can change the method signature to accept object and perform conversion if it is not `null`

Comment: Hi! this worked for me! just need to add '<%# GetValidDate((string)Eval("VisitDate"))%>' Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi! is there also a way I can number the items? 1. Date1 , 2 Date2 ... N DateN?

Comment: @Katherine : 1.FirstComment: that is not good conversion, please see the updates in the answer; 2. secondComment: I dnt get what you are asking; sometimes i can help you if you more clear about the requirement

Comment: ! oh! thank you! about my second question, I want to list it with numbering. like "1." On the first date, "2." on the next and so on

Comment: @Katherine : may be a global counter variable solves this, with a return statement `return counter++.ToString() + dateObject.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");`

Comment: Thank you for your help!